# increment a value at uBoot prompt?

Tags: linux, bootloader, u-boot

I'm hoping to find a way to increment a value in RAM from uBoots command prompt.

in short, address 0xc4000000 on my device is a temp variable that I need to increment

thoughts?

- can I put the value into an environment variable and inc it there?
- is there a trick I can use to increment it?

Comment: Do you understand what is [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) ? Have you booted the kernel? And hardware resets are not easily countable (unless you have a very specific hardware device).

Comment: Ill clear up the question - the application doesn't matter.   the question is how to increment a memory address using the uBoot command line commands (I'd prefer not to add a uBoot command just for this)

Answer (score 11):

You can use the U-Boot command *setexpr*
, which takes the destination, variable 1, an operation and variable 2.

```
U-Boot> setexpr count ${count} + 1
```

However in some older version of U-Boot this command is not included.
If this is the case, you may want to re-compile an updated U-Boot.

If you can't do that and you're still desparate, you could write nested "if" statements to increment your number as a string.  If you need to store this for later, save it off to your non-volatile storeage (NAND or EEPROM) periodically.  If you do this then count in HEX and you'll have to compare your string against "f", "1f", "2f", etc. depending on how high you need to count.

Here is a basic code that will work:

```
setenv ones "."
setenv tens "."
setenv hundreds "."
setenv thousands "."
setenv full ".++++++++++"
setenv doCountOnes 'if test ${ones} = ${full}; then setenv ones ".";setenv tens ${tens}+ ; else setenv ones ${ones}+; fi'
setenv doCountTens 'if test ${tens} = ${full}; then setenv tens ".";setenv hundreds ${hundreds}+ ; fi'
setenv doCountHundreds 'if test ${hundreds} = ${full}; then setenv hundreds ".";setenv thousands ${thousands}+ ; fi'
setenv printCount 'echo;echo **********************************************;echo ${thousands} Thousand ${hundreds} Hundred ${tens} Ten and ${ones};echo **********************************************'
setenv doCount 'run doCountOnes; run doCountTens; run doCountHundreds'
setenv mainLoop 'run yourTestHere; run doCount; run printCount'
```

To run this script type:

```
run mainLoop
```